# Plotting histogram in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this and wish to make a frequency histogram.

```
 1.19714
    1.04872
    0.188158
    1
    1.02339
    1
    1
    1
0.38496
1.31858
1
1.33654
0.945736
1.00877
0.413445
0.810127
1
0.625
0.492857
0.187156
0.95847
```

I want to plot a frequency histogram, with x axis bins from -1 to 1. How can I do this in pandas?

Answer (score 1):

`pandas` has a [built-in](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.hist.html) histogram function.

Assuming your dataframe is called `df`:

```
import numpy as np

df.hist(bins=np.arange(-1,1,0.1))
```

[image]

Comment: I get this error: TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable